# which is the best way or best performance to join two mutables list in kotlin?

Tags: performance, kotlin, mutablelist

hello I would like to know which is the best performance to join two mutables list

`if list1.addall (list2)
with foreach
list1?.let { list1 -> list2?.let(list1::addAll) }`

or a map or something like that..?

Answer (score 2):

If the first list is mutable and you want to modify it, just use `+=` operator:

```
list1 += list2
```

It delegates to `addAll` member function, appending all elements of `list2` to `list1`

If you don't want to mutate the original list, use `+` operator:

```
val result = list1 + list2
```

It concatenates two lists into the third new list. Compared to creating an empty ArrayList by hand and calling `addAll` on it, this operator has an advantage of presizing the resulting ArrayList to an estimated size, so it helps to spare ArrayList's storage array reallocations.

Answer (score 1):

**If `list1` is mutable and you can modify it:**

```
list1.addAll(list1.size, list2)
```

and in `list1` you will have `list1 + list2`

**If you can not modify you can create `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` and add all**

```
val newList = ArrayList<Int>()

newList.addAll(list1)
newList.addAll(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If both of them are of same type, then you can use flat map in Kotlin.
For example,

```
val listA = mutableList<String>()
val listB = mutableList<String>()
```

Then you can merge both of them like below

```
val mergedList = listOf(listA, listB).flatten()
```

or

```
val mergedList = listOf(listA, listB).flatMap { it }
```

This way it's efficient, more readable and less code!! Happy coding with kotlin!

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to create a LinkedList because it's always cheap to add items into it, whereas an ArrayList might sometimes allocate more space if you reach the end of the array.

See this for more info on the topic [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

If `list1` isn't a LinkedList already, keeping in mind `mutableListOf()` returns an ArrayList, then you can create a third list like so:

```
 val newList = LinkedList<Int>()
    list1.forEach {
        newList += it
    }

    list2.forEach {
        newList += it
    }
```